# Cannot find module discord.js-commando

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot using NodeJS. However, when I try to run it, it tells me that it cannot find the module, `discord.js-commando`.

Here is my bot's code.

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class DiceRollCommand extends commando.Command {
constructor(client) {
    supern  (client,  {
        name: 'roll'
        group: 'random'
        memberName: 'roll'
        description: 'Rolls a die'
    });
}

  async run(message, args){
      var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      message.reply("You rolled a " + roll);
  }
}

module.exports = DiceRollCommand;
```

`

Comment: Did you `npm install discord.js-commando --save`?

Answer (score 0):

For Discord, both the Discord.js and Commando modules need to be installed, and they are separate. Also make sure you're at least on Node 7.6

Try:

`npm install discord.js-commando --save`

Update:

`npm install discord.js-commando --save -g`

Use the global flag. So if your directory structure looks like:

```
nebula
    -commands
        -random
            -file.js
    -node_modules
    -index.js
    -file.json
    -file2.json
    -package
    -package-lock
```

It means that Node expects there to be a node_modules in the same directory as file.js, which it cannot find. Either move it to the root directory, or install the modules globally.

Comment: yes, i installed both modules,    npm install discord.js-commando --save and  
    npm install --save discord.js

Comment: Can you tell us what your directory structure looks like for this project? Might help us pinpoint whether the module(s) are in the right place.

Comment: yep sure-- E:\nebula --in that folder i have a folder named-- commands --which has an other folder named-- random --in it, which contains my js file. in the-- nebula --folder i also have a folder named-- node_modules,-- a js file named --index-- and two .json files -- package -- and --package-lock

Comment: I have tried installing the modules globally and in the root directory but when i use node --harmony .  it still wont run saying it can't find the module, any ideas?

Comment: Alright, as a last effort, perhaps try copying the node_modules folder into the same folder as the file you're trying to run, and also make sure that commando is actually in the node_modules folder. Or copy the file you're trying to run to the same level as index.js.

Comment: @DriesRooryck try my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is the node_modules directory in your home folder? If it is, and your program is in a different folder, you have to do this:
`const commando = require('../node_modules/discord.js-commando');`

'..' goes back a directory. So if your program is in a folder inside a folder, you would have to do this:

`const commando = require('../../node_modules/discord.js-commando');`

I had the same problem and this fixed it. But, if it still doesn't work, comment how your project is structured and where the node_modules and your program directories are.